# Program skipping over if statement in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to update a clients details with a function. But it doesn't work. I debug the program and I realized that it never goes into the `if`. I don't know why?

This is the function:

```
def UpdateClient(self,id,cnp,name,adress):
    for i in range (len(self.clients.get_all())):
        if self.clients.get_all()[i].get_id==id:
            self.clients.get_all()[i].set_name(name)
            self.clients.get_all()[i].set_cnp(cnp)
            self.clients.get_all()[i].set_adress(adress)
```

When I try to update the client, I give the `id`, `name`, `cnp`, and `adress`, but when I print the list nothing is changed. I cannot go into the `if` with the debugger because it said that they are never equal. Why?

Comment: `self.clients.get_all()[i].get_id()` ?

Comment: and how could i change it?

Comment: `get_id` sounds like a function. Perhaps it should be `.get_id() == id` ?

Answer (score 5):

Note that `get_id` is not the same as `get_id()`. The former references the method, while the latter actually calls it.

In addition, consider simplifying your code by writing more idiomatic Python. For example:

```
for client in self.clients.get_all():
        if client.get_id() == id:
            client.set_name(name)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is you are making your `check` as `get_id == id` but it is a function. Your `if` should be like:

```
if self.clients.get_all()[i].get_id()==id:
#                                   ^ making it a function call
```

Also, better way to do this is by storing `self.clients.get_all()` in a separate variable. Hence, your code should look like:

```
def UpdateClient(self,id,cnp,name,adress):
    clients = self.clients.get_all()
    for i in range (len(clients)):
        if clients[i].get_id()==id:
            clients[i].set_name(name)
            clients[i].set_cnp(cnp)
            clients[i].set_adress(adress)
```

Comment: `get_id` should be method call, that was issue

Comment: this doesnt address the question at all ...  although there may be a grain of truth you need to explain why you think this is the correct solution (as an aside i think your assumtion about random order of get_all is likely faulty)

Comment: If you are just randomly going to guess at the API, you should probably make it a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: it is better to do it like this, I agree but doesn't address the actual issue

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga he cant comment ... he does not have enough rep

Comment: @JoranBeasley Then he should wait until he has more rep...

Comment: not disagreeing :P but just saying

Comment: Fixed the answer. Let's help him have some reputation so that it won't bother him for next comment. As per SO policy, it is fine to upvote the correct answer ;)

Comment: lol :P good job I guess :P